# failed when i want to load model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

please help to solve this issue.

```
    # MODEL CNN-LSTM
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype="string")
    x = text_vectorizer(inputs)
    x = embedding(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(x)
    x = layers.LSTM(128, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)(x) # return vector for whole sequence
    out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    out = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(out)
    outputs = layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax")(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="model_LSTM")
    
    METRICS = [
            tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives(name='TruePositive'),
            tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives(name='FalsePositive'),
            tf.keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(name='TrueNegative'),
            tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(name='FalseNegative'), 
            tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
            tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
            tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),
            tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
          ]
```

when I want to load the model it happened. i running in google collab

```
    TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.ragged.ragged_tensor.RaggedTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: tf.RaggedTensor(values=tf.RaggedTensor(values=Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(None, 128), dtype=float32), row_splits=Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int64)), row_splits=Tensor("conv1d_4/conv1d/RaggedExpandDims/RaggedFromUniformRowLength/RowPartitionFromUniformRowLength/mul:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

what should I do?

Comment: Hi Fendi Irfan, Welcome to StackOverFlow. Have you trained your model?

Comment: Can you share complete code to replicate your issue?so that we can try to help you. Thanks!